# Uncurrying/tupling a multidimensional array in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

Say I have an e.g. two-dimensional array, and I'm storing some indexes in tuples:

```
val testArray = Array.ofDim[Double](3, 4)
val ixs = (1,2)
```

I'd like to use those tuples directly, e.g. `testArray(ixs)`. However, `Function.tupled(testedArray _)` returns "_ must follow method; cannot follow Array[Array[Double]]".

Is this because `Array` is not actually a subtype of `Function3`? **If so, how to go around this limitation? Should I use implicits to extend `ArrayOps` or something similar?** Currently, I'm storing the data in a `Map` as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays of arrays are not given special treatment; they're just arrays of (something).  Thus, there's no special way to access them via tuples.  But as you've suggested, you can create such a way.

You can

```
implicit class ArrayOps2D[@specialized T](xss: Array[Array[T]]) {
  def apply(ij: (Int, Int)) = xss(ij._1)(ij._2)
  def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = xss(i)(j)
  def update(ij: (Int, Int), t: T) { xss(ij._1)(ij._2) = t }
  def update(i: Int, j: Int, t: T) { xss(i)(j) = t }
}
```

You might think of doing

```
implicit class ArrayOps2D[T](val xss: Array[Array[T]]) extends AnyVal {
  def apply(ij: (Int, Int)) = xss(ij._1)(ij._2)
  def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = xss(i)(j)
  def update(ij: (Int, Int), t: T) { xss(ij._1)(ij._2) = t }
  def update(i: Int, j: Int, t: T) { xss(i)(j) = t }
}
```

but this doesn't work as well in my opinion.  Due to implementation limitations, you can't specialize an AnyVal.  Furthermore, the former is probably better if you are using primitives a lot since it avoids boxing the primitives (and the JVM can handle avoiding object creation, hopefully), while the latter is more efficient if you have non-primitives most of the time (e.g. strings) since you don't (formally) create an object.  But your example uses primitives.

In any case, if you do this you'll have seamless two-index addressing with tuples and pairs of arguments (as I've written it).  You *cannot* use the update methods completely seamlessly, though!  They will mostly work, but they *won't* automatically promote numeric types.  So if you have doubles and you write `a(1,2) = 3` it will fail, because it doesn't find an `update(Int, Int, Int)` method, and doesn't think to use the `update(Int, Int, Double)`.  But you can fix that yourself by doing the conversion (or in this case writing `3d`).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive discussion of the trade-offs between the two approaches.

Comment: Also, you can now (Scala 2.10+) "specialize" AnyVal with value classes, although  implementation-wise, it's not as [straightforward as simple "subclassing"](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - I'm not sure what you mean.  You can't actually use the `specialized` keyword in 2.10, and I already cover the generic unboxed-array-boxed-elements version under "you might think of doing".

Comment: Heh, a little miscommunication here, and due to my inferior knowledge of Scala nonetheless - I wasn't aware of the `specialized` keyword and assumed you meant the general OOP term. In that context, yes, that was covered under the section of your answer you mentioned.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - Fair enough.  (Technically it's an annotation, not a keyword--I misspoke above.)